# Laggy windows, sore eyes

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, monitor

I recently made a switch from Windows to Ubuntu. I think I downloaded the latest nvidia drivers.

After a few days of using Ubuntu my eyes started to feel weird and sore. I've been using Windows on my PC for hours for years and my eyes never hurt.

The windows I open on Ubuntu are kinda lagging/dragging slowly. Also, the text I read seems like 1.5% blurry. I don't know how to explain it, it just feels very slightly off.

Comment: That's certainly odd. How did you download the nvidia drivers? Did you use the nvidia website download or did you do it through apt-get? If you did it through nvidia's website, there's a fair chance the drivers won't work very well, as they haven't been tested yet.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean. Install the MS TTF-fonts. https://www.ostechnix.com/install-microsoft-windows-fonts-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: I used system setting/additional drivers/propetiary-tested.